# Get a list of numbers from range(s) of number

Tags: r, list, dataframe, numbers, range

I have a data frame where one column contains a range (or ranges) of numbers. I would like to turn this into a list of numbers based of the given range.

Example input:

```
"35-40"
```

or

```
"35-43, 45-47"
```

This should yield:

```
[1]  35 36 37 38 39 40
```

and

```
[1]  35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 45 46 47
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a split and with `Map`, get the numbers

```
do.call(Map, c(`:`, lapply(strsplit(df1$v1, '-'), as.numeric)))
#[[1]]
# [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

#[[2]]
#[1] 43 44 45 46 47
```

---

If we need to find the sequence within the string

```
lapply(strsplit(df1$v1, "-"), function(x) Reduce(`:`, as.numeric(x)))
#[1]]
#[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43

#[[2]]
#[1] 45 46 47
```

#### Update

If we have multiple elements in a string

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("35-43", "45-47", "30-42, 25-27")), 
.Names = "v1", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L), class = "data.frame")

lapply(strsplit(df1$v1, ", "), function(x) do.call(c, 
    lapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(y) Reduce(`:`, as.numeric(y)))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("35-43", "45-47")), .Names = "v1", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This only works for a range of numbers only but not when the value has a multiple ranges (E.g. 35-43, 45-47 This should give [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 45 46 47)

Comment: @TaraSutjarittham  Please update your post with a dput of your example.  It is not clear how u r getting the output

Comment: Hi @akrun, sorry the question wasn't clear enough. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval(parse(...))` as follows,

```
eval(parse(text = sub('-', ':', '35-40')))
#[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

or

```
unlist(lapply(sub('-', ':', c('35-40', '45-47')), function(i) eval(parse(text = i))))
#[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 45 46 47
```

**EDIT**

Based on your latest edit, then,

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ', '), function(i) {
           ind <- sub('-', ':', i); unlist(lapply(ind, function(j) eval(parse(text = j))))
  }))

 #[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 45 46 47
```

Answer (score 1):

we use substr to extract parts of string to get beginning and end of numeric list. we use as.numeric to convert strings extracted  to numbers. we use the colon to create the list of numbers  . it will also work for multiple parts of list

```
> input
[1] "35-40"
> instart=substr(input,1,2)
> instart
[1] "35"
> inend=substr(input,4,5)
> inend
[1] "40"
> newlist=as.numeric(instart):as.numeric(inend)
> newlist
[1] 35 36 37 38 39 40
```